# Need to clean install Yosemite without knowing or resetting password

Tags: macos, startup, password

I have a laptop that I would like to get in working order. There are 2 main issues:

1. I forgot the password.
2. When I boot the laptop, I am seeing the flashing folder with a question mark which indicates that the system software cannot be found.

I have a bootable USB with Yosemite on it, so I attempted to boot the computer and hold down the 'Option' key so that I could reformat the hard drive. However, I was prompted for a password which I do not know.

I also tried booting into single user mode and resetting the password, but it gets stuck on a blank white screen without ever reaching single user mode (likely due to the lack of found system files).

Does anyone know how I can clean install Yosemite on this laptop without knowing or being able to reset the password?

Comment: Plain out of luck on that one. But if you have it set up with Apple ID, you could use that to recover it.

Comment: Boot from USB, then use Disk Utility (from USB) and reformat your drive = all information is lost.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I actually don't mind losing all the information. if you have a suggestion that will work but loses all the information, that would be great!